# how to decode json data to an array in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, json

I have created an API and the results are given out in json in the following format:

```
{"response":"ok","data":[{"file_name":"sample file name one","server_url":"someurl","file_thumb":"images\/7ibysd4f8wiy_t.jpg"},{"file_name":"sample file name two","server_url":"someurl","file_thumb":"images\/jm3t6aat8uhq_t.jpg"}]}
```

till now I was using the following function:

```
- (NSArray*) jsonToArray:(NSString *)responseData{

    NSData* data = [responseData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSArray *values = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];  // if you are expecting  the JSON string to be in form of array else use NSDictionary instead

    return values;

}
```

and then I would get the array like:

```
data_array = [self jsonToArray:data_js];
[data_array valueForKey:@"data"]
```

but how I be able to loop through the `data` array? is that possible with the current method?

Comment: "how to decode json data to an array in xcode" - you can't, Xcode is not a JSON parser.

Comment: so what data can xcode parse easily? what data should I return in my API to be able to read it easily on xcode?

Comment: At best, Xcode can parse its own data formats (for example, Xcode project files). I bet you don't want to parse JSON using Xcode, but using **your application.** Those are two different things, and if this is indeed the case, then your question has **nothing** to do with Xcode whatsoever.

Comment: my bad, I meant objective-c not xcode in particular...

Comment: Then have a look at the answer I've posted a link to, you are most probably looking for Objective-C fast enumeration: `for (id element in array) { ... }`

Comment: Based on the data shown, each element in the array is probably an NSDictionary. Iterate through the array and work with each element as a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the new enumerateObjectsUsingBlock API on NSDictionary and NSArray. You can call that on your variable returned by NSJSONSerialization

It's super simple and gives you a little bit cleaner code than fast enumeration.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: